# How to get URL of GWT EntryPoint?

Tags: gwt, hyperlink

I'd like to create a Hyperlink from one GWT module to another. Instead of hard-coding a URL string, I want to programmatically convert a module class to its associated URL so that when the class is refactored it does not result in broken links. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: I want to be able to look up the URL for EntryPoint "B" from inside EntryPoint "A".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An EntryPoint doesn't have a URL, an EntryPoint's URL is any page includes the relevant `nocache.js` file, which can be any number of pages in your site.

So there is no programmatic way to get the one-and-only page that includes a given EntryPoint, since it can be any page that includes the script.

Comment: That's a shame. I can't think of a reason to ever include the same EntryPoint in two separate html files and this means the code is now harder to refactor. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

Use `GWT#getHostPageBaseURL()` or `GWT#getModuleBaseURL()` to construct relative paths

Comment: This retrieves the current URL, not the URL of other EntryPoints.